# Why doesn't this work

Tags: psexec

Why doesn't this work? I want to copy the file to the remote machine and run it.

```
psexec \\epo-test -c C:\temp\Avmr64.msi /Silent
```

Heres the error I get

PsExec could not start Avmr64.msi on epo-test:
The system cannot find the file specified.

I am trying to copy Avmr64.msi over to epo-test and run a silent install but I get this 
PsExec could not start Avmr64.msi on epo-test:
The system cannot find the file specified.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that are interested heres the answer

```
psexec -u domain\username \\system -s -i -d msiexec.exe /i "\\share\folder\msifile" /qb
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to run here is "/Silent". Try instead:

```
psexec \\epo-test -c C:\temp\Avmr64.msi "C:\temp\Avmr64.msi /Silent"
```

or something in that fashion.

Comment: What's the point in trying without quotes? Try psexec \\epo-test -c C:\temp\Avmr64.msi "Avmr64.msi /Silent" If this still doesn't work, then I'm sorry I have no clues.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below ( untested ):

```
psexec \\epo-test -c C:\temp\Avmr64.msi  "msiexec /i /passive Avmr64.msi"
```

http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic2542.html

Comment: @user770022 - how can it be same error now? Just add the error again please. Anyway, look at the link in my answer and figure out the exact thing you want to run

Comment: C:\Users\raw008>psexec \\epo-test -c C:\temp\Avmr64.msi  "msiexec /i /passive c:\temp\Avmr64.msiAvmr64.msi"

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


PsExec could not start Avmr64.msi on epo-test:
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @user770022 Why are you adding `C:\temp\Avmr64.msi` within the quotes? Just try what I had given. In the remote machine it will not be located at `C:\temp`

Comment: @user770022 - I dont meant the quotes. After the msiexec, just use Avmr64.msi and not C:\temp\Avmr64.msi

Comment: I have tried every which way none of the ways I've tried work

Comment: Hi there, I'm having exactly the same problem (with a different MSI) and see the error PsExec could not start SBERA.msi on remotemachine: the system cannot find the file specified.